# react native app failed to run on emulator "Unfortunately app has stopped'

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator, react-native

I created a React native app using the command "**react-native init test2**"(didn't edit the app)

•The app was built without an error

> • But when I run it on the emulator the app crashes by giving the error
>   Unfortunately test2 has stopped
>
> > • I get an error message in the Run section(shown below)

[image]

**Error message in the run section◌̬**
[image]

```
11/10 16:53:06: Launching 'app' on myavd.
$ adb shell am start -n "com.test2/com.test2.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Connected to process 3770 on device 'emulator-5554'.
Capturing and displaying logcat messages from application. This behavior can be disabled in the "Logcat output" section of the "Debugger" settings page.
I/art: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.test2-1/lib/x86_64
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.test2, PID: 3770
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application com.test2.MainApplication: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.test2.MainApplication" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.test2-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.test2-1/lib/x86_64, /vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]
        at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:578)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4680)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1405)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.test2.MainApplication" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.test2-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.test2-1/lib/x86_64, /vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:981)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:573)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4680) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1405) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
        Suppressed: java.io.IOException: No original dex files found for dex location /data/app/com.test2-1/base.apk
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFileNative(Native Method)
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFile(DexFile.java:295)
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:80)
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:59)
        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.loadDexFile(DexPathList.java:279)
        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.makePathElements(DexPathList.java:248)
        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.<init>(DexPathList.java:120)
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.<init>(BaseDexClassLoader.java:48)
        at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.<init>(PathClassLoader.java:65)
        at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoader(ApplicationLoaders.java:58)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.getClassLoader(LoadedApk.java:376)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:568)
                ... 9 more
        Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.test2.MainApplication
        at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
        at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
        at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
                ... 12 more
     Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack trace available
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 3770 SIG: 9
Process 3770 terminated.
```

*I didn't edit the code,this it the original app generated using* **react-native init test2**

> **I tried to install the apk on my android phone, the app fails to install so I think the issue is with the built app file**

Screenshot of the cmd when app was built
[image]

```
C:\test>react-native init test1
This will walk you through creating a new React Native project in C:\test\test1
Using yarn v1.19.1
Installing react-native...
yarn add v1.19.1
info No lockfile found.
[1/4] Resolving packages...
warning react-native > create-react-class > fbjs > core-js@1.2.7: core-js@<2.6.8 is no longer maintained. Please, upgrade to core-js@3 or at least to actual version of core-js@2.
warning react-native > @react-native-community/cli > metro > jest-haste-map > fsevents@1.2.9: One of your dependencies needs to upgrade to fsevents v2: 1) Proper nodejs v10+ support 2) No more fetching binaries from AWS, smaller package size
[2/4] Fetching packages...
info fsevents@1.2.9: The platform "win32" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@1.2.9" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
warning "react-native > metro-react-native-babel-transformer@0.56.3" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@*".
warning " > react-native@0.61.4" has unmet peer dependency "react@16.9.0".
[4/4] Building fresh packages...
success Saved lockfile.
success Saved 388 new dependencies.
info Direct dependencies
└─ react-native@0.61.4
info All dependencies
├─ @babel/generator@7.7.2
├─ @babel/helper-builder-binary-assignment-operator-visitor@7.7.0
├─ @babel/helper-builder-react-jsx@7.7.0
├─ @babel/helper-call-delegate@7.7.0
├─ @babel/helper-create-regexp-features-plugin@7.7.2
├─ @babel/helper-define-map@7.7.0
├─ @babel/helper-explode-assignable-expression@7.7.0
├─ @babel/helper-get-function-arity@7.7.0
├─ @babel/helper-hoist-variables@7.7.0
├─ @babel/helper-module-imports@7.7.0
├─ @babel/helper-module-transforms@7.7.0
├─ @babel/helper-regex@7.5.5
├─ @babel/helper-remap-async-to-generator@7.7.0
├─ @babel/helper-wrap-function@7.7.0
├─ @babel/helpers@7.7.0
├─ @babel/highlight@7.5.0
├─ @babel/parser@7.7.3
├─ @babel/plugin-external-helpers@7.2.0
├─ @babel/plugin-proposal-export-default-from@7.5.2
├─ @babel/plugin-syntax-class-properties@7.2.0
├─ @babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import@7.2.0
├─ @babel/plugin-syntax-export-default-from@7.2.0
├─ @babel/plugin-syntax-nullish-coalescing-operator@7.2.0
├─ @babel/plugin-syntax-object-rest-spread@7.2.0
├─ @babel/plugin-syntax-optional-catch-binding@7.2.0
├─ @babel/plugin-syntax-optional-chaining@7.2.0
├─ @babel/plugin-syntax-typescript@7.3.3
├─ @babel/plugin-transform-async-to-generator@7.7.0
├─ @babel/plugin-transform-block-scoped-functions@7.2.0
├─ @babel/plugin-transform-exponentiation-operator@7.2.0
├─ @babel/plugin-transform-member-expression-literals@7.2.0
├─ @babel/plugin-transform-object-assign@7.2.0
├─ @babel/plugin-transform-object-super@7.5.5
├─ @babel/plugin-transform-property-literals@7.2.0
├─ @babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx-source@7.5.0
├─ @babel/plugin-transform-regenerator@7.7.0
├─ @babel/plugin-transform-runtime@7.6.2
├─ @babel/plugin-transform-sticky-regex@7.2.0
├─ @babel/plugin-transform-typescript@7.7.2
├─ @babel/plugin-transform-unicode-regex@7.7.0
├─ @babel/register@7.7.0
├─ @babel/runtime@7.7.2
├─ @cnakazawa/watch@1.0.3
├─ @hapi/address@2.1.2
├─ @hapi/bourne@1.3.2
├─ @hapi/hoek@8.5.0
├─ @hapi/joi@15.1.1
├─ @hapi/topo@3.1.6
├─ @jest/fake-timers@24.9.0
├─ @react-native-community/cli-platform-android@3.0.0-alpha.7
├─ @react-native-community/cli-platform-ios@3.0.0-alpha.7
├─ @react-native-community/cli-types@3.0.0-alpha.7
├─ @react-native-community/cli@3.0.0-alpha.7
├─ @types/istanbul-lib-report@1.1.1
├─ @types/istanbul-reports@1.1.1
├─ @types/mkdirp@0.5.2
├─ @types/node-notifier@5.4.0
├─ @types/semver@6.2.0
├─ @types/stack-utils@1.0.1
├─ @types/ws@6.0.3
├─ @types/yargs-parser@13.1.0
├─ @types/yargs@13.0.3
├─ abort-controller@3.0.0
├─ accepts@1.3.7
├─ ansi-colors@1.1.0
├─ ansi-cyan@0.1.1
├─ ansi-escapes@3.2.0
├─ ansi-fragments@0.2.1
├─ ansi-gray@0.1.1
├─ ansi-red@0.1.1
├─ ansi-regex@4.1.0
├─ argparse@1.0.10
├─ arr-flatten@1.1.0
├─ array-filter@0.0.1
├─ array-map@0.0.0
├─ array-reduce@0.0.0
├─ array-slice@0.2.3
├─ art@0.10.3
├─ asap@2.0.6
├─ assign-symbols@1.0.0
├─ astral-regex@1.0.0
├─ async-limiter@1.0.1
├─ async@2.6.3
├─ atob@2.1.2
├─ babel-plugin-dynamic-import-node@2.3.0
├─ babel-plugin-syntax-trailing-function-commas@7.0.0-beta.0
├─ balanced-match@1.0.0
├─ base@0.11.2
├─ base64-js@1.3.1
├─ basic-auth@2.0.1
├─ big-integer@1.6.47
├─ bplist-creator@0.0.8
├─ bplist-parser@0.2.0
├─ brace-expansion@1.1.11
├─ braces@2.3.2
├─ bser@2.1.1
├─ buffer-crc32@0.2.13
├─ bytes@3.0.0
├─ cache-base@1.0.1
├─ caller-callsite@2.0.0
├─ caller-path@2.0.0
├─ capture-exit@2.0.0
├─ chardet@0.4.2
├─ ci-info@2.0.0
├─ class-utils@0.3.6
├─ cli-spinners@2.2.0
├─ cli-width@2.2.0
├─ cliui@3.2.0
├─ clone@1.0.4
├─ code-point-at@1.1.0
├─ collection-visit@1.0.0
├─ color-convert@1.9.3
├─ color-name@1.1.3
├─ color-support@1.1.3
├─ colorette@1.1.0
├─ command-exists@1.2.8
├─ commander@2.20.3
├─ commondir@1.0.1
├─ compressible@2.0.17
├─ compression@1.7.4
├─ concat-map@0.0.1
├─ concat-stream@1.6.2
├─ convert-source-map@1.7.0
├─ copy-descriptor@0.1.1
├─ core-js@2.6.10
├─ core-util-is@1.0.2
├─ cosmiconfig@5.2.1
├─ create-react-class@15.6.3
├─ cross-spawn@5.1.0
├─ dayjs@1.8.17
├─ debug@2.6.9
├─ decode-uri-component@0.2.0
├─ deepmerge@3.3.0
├─ defaults@1.0.3
├─ define-properties@1.1.3
├─ denodeify@1.2.1
├─ destroy@1.0.4
├─ ee-first@1.1.1
├─ encoding@0.1.12
├─ end-of-stream@1.4.4
├─ envinfo@7.4.0
├─ error-ex@1.3.2
├─ errorhandler@1.5.1
├─ esprima@4.0.1
├─ esutils@2.0.3
├─ etag@1.8.1
├─ event-target-shim@5.0.1
├─ eventemitter3@3.1.2
├─ expand-brackets@2.1.4
├─ external-editor@2.2.0
├─ extglob@2.0.4
├─ fancy-log@1.3.3
├─ fbjs-css-vars@1.0.2
├─ fbjs-scripts@1.2.0
├─ figures@2.0.0
├─ fill-range@4.0.0
├─ finalhandler@1.1.2
├─ find-cache-dir@2.1.0
├─ for-in@1.0.2
├─ fresh@0.5.2
├─ fs-extra@7.0.1
├─ fs.realpath@1.0.0
├─ function-bind@1.1.1
├─ get-stream@4.1.0
├─ get-value@2.0.6
├─ glob@7.1.6
├─ growly@1.3.0
├─ has-symbols@1.0.0
├─ has-value@1.0.0
├─ hermes-engine@0.2.1
├─ hosted-git-info@2.8.5
├─ http-errors@1.7.3
├─ iconv-lite@0.4.24
├─ image-size@0.6.3
├─ import-fresh@2.0.0
├─ imurmurhash@0.1.4
├─ inflight@1.0.6
├─ inherits@2.0.4
├─ inquirer@3.3.0
├─ invert-kv@1.0.0
├─ is-accessor-descriptor@1.0.0
├─ is-arrayish@0.2.1
├─ is-ci@2.0.0
├─ is-data-descriptor@1.0.0
├─ is-descriptor@1.0.2
├─ is-directory@0.3.1
├─ is-plain-object@2.0.4
├─ is-promise@2.1.0
├─ is-windows@1.0.2
├─ isarray@1.0.0
├─ isexe@2.0.0
├─ jest-get-type@24.9.0
├─ jest-message-util@24.9.0
├─ jest-mock@24.9.0
├─ jest-serializer@24.9.0
├─ jest-util@24.9.0
├─ jest-validate@24.9.0
├─ jest-worker@24.9.0
├─ jetifier@1.6.4
├─ js-tokens@4.0.0
├─ jsc-android@245459.0.0
├─ jsesc@2.5.2
├─ json-parse-better-errors@1.0.2
├─ json-stable-stringify@1.0.1
├─ json5@2.1.1
├─ jsonfile@4.0.0
├─ kind-of@3.2.2
├─ klaw@1.3.1
├─ lcid@1.0.0
├─ leven@3.1.0
├─ load-json-file@2.0.0
├─ locate-path@3.0.0
├─ lodash@4.17.15
├─ log-symbols@2.2.0
├─ logkitty@0.6.1
├─ loose-envify@1.4.0
├─ lru-cache@4.1.5
├─ make-dir@2.1.0
├─ makeerror@1.0.11
├─ map-age-cleaner@0.1.3
├─ map-visit@1.0.0
├─ mem@1.1.0
├─ merge-stream@1.0.1
├─ metro-babel-register@0.56.3
├─ metro-config@0.56.3
├─ metro-inspector-proxy@0.56.3
├─ metro-minify-uglify@0.56.3
├─ metro@0.56.3
├─ mime-db@1.42.0
├─ mime-types@2.1.11
├─ mime@2.4.4
├─ minimatch@3.0.4
├─ mixin-deep@1.3.2
├─ mkdirp@0.5.1
├─ morgan@1.9.1
├─ ms@2.1.2
├─ mute-stream@0.0.7
├─ nanomatch@1.2.13
├─ negotiator@0.6.2
├─ nice-try@1.0.5
├─ node-fetch@2.6.0
├─ node-int64@0.4.0
├─ node-modules-regexp@1.0.0
├─ node-notifier@5.4.3
├─ normalize-package-data@2.5.0
├─ normalize-path@2.1.1
├─ number-is-nan@1.0.1
├─ ob1@0.56.3
├─ object-assign@4.1.1
├─ object-copy@0.1.0
├─ object-keys@1.1.1
├─ object.assign@4.1.0
├─ on-headers@1.0.2
├─ once@1.4.0
├─ onetime@2.0.1
├─ open@6.4.0
├─ options@0.0.6
├─ ora@3.4.0
├─ os-locale@2.1.0
├─ os-tmpdir@1.0.2
├─ p-defer@1.0.0
├─ p-is-promise@2.1.0
├─ p-limit@2.2.1
├─ p-locate@3.0.0
├─ p-try@2.2.0
├─ parse-json@4.0.0
├─ parse-node-version@1.0.1
├─ pascalcase@0.1.1
├─ path-is-absolute@1.0.1
├─ path-key@2.0.1
├─ path-parse@1.0.6
├─ path-type@2.0.0
├─ pirates@4.0.1
├─ pkg-dir@3.0.0
├─ plist@3.0.1
├─ plugin-error@0.1.2
├─ posix-character-classes@0.1.1
├─ pretty-format@24.9.0
├─ private@0.1.8
├─ process-nextick-args@2.0.1
├─ prop-types@15.7.2
├─ pseudomap@1.0.2
├─ pump@3.0.0
├─ range-parser@1.2.1
├─ react-devtools-core@3.6.3
├─ react-is@16.11.0
├─ react-native@0.61.4
├─ read-pkg-up@2.0.0
├─ read-pkg@2.0.0
├─ readable-stream@2.3.6
├─ regenerate-unicode-properties@8.1.0
├─ regenerator-transform@0.14.1
├─ regexpu-core@4.6.0
├─ regjsgen@0.5.1
├─ regjsparser@0.6.0
├─ remove-trailing-separator@1.1.0
├─ repeat-element@1.1.3
├─ resolve-from@3.0.0
├─ resolve-url@0.2.1
├─ resolve@1.12.0
├─ restore-cursor@2.0.0
├─ ret@0.1.15
├─ rimraf@2.7.1
├─ rsvp@4.8.5
├─ run-async@2.3.0
├─ rx-lite-aggregates@4.0.8
├─ rx-lite@4.0.8
├─ rxjs@5.5.12
├─ safer-buffer@2.1.2
├─ sane@4.1.0
├─ sax@1.2.4
├─ scheduler@0.15.0
├─ semver@5.7.1
├─ send@0.17.1
├─ serialize-error@2.1.0
├─ serve-static@1.14.1
├─ set-blocking@2.0.0
├─ set-value@2.0.1
├─ setprototypeof@1.1.1
├─ shebang-regex@1.0.0
├─ shell-quote@1.6.1
├─ shellwords@0.1.1
├─ signal-exit@3.0.2
├─ simple-plist@1.1.0
├─ slice-ansi@2.1.0
├─ slide@1.1.6
├─ snapdragon-node@2.1.1
├─ snapdragon-util@3.0.1
├─ source-map-resolve@0.5.2
├─ source-map-support@0.5.16
├─ source-map-url@0.4.0
├─ spdx-correct@3.1.0
├─ spdx-exceptions@2.2.0
├─ split-string@3.1.0
├─ sprintf-js@1.0.3
├─ stack-utils@1.0.2
├─ stacktrace-parser@0.1.7
├─ static-extend@0.1.2
├─ statuses@1.5.0
├─ stream-buffers@2.2.0
├─ string_decoder@1.1.1
├─ string-width@2.1.1
├─ strip-ansi@3.0.1
├─ strip-bom@3.0.0
├─ sudo-prompt@9.0.0
├─ supports-color@5.5.0
├─ symbol-observable@1.0.1
├─ temp@0.8.3
├─ throat@4.1.0
├─ through@2.3.8
├─ through2@2.0.5
├─ time-stamp@1.1.0
├─ tmp@0.0.33
├─ to-fast-properties@2.0.0
├─ to-object-path@0.3.0
├─ to-regex-range@2.1.1
├─ toidentifier@1.0.0
├─ type-fest@0.7.1
├─ typedarray@0.0.6
├─ uglify-es@3.3.9
├─ ultron@1.0.2
├─ unicode-canonical-property-names-ecmascript@1.0.4
├─ unicode-match-property-ecmascript@1.0.4
├─ unicode-match-property-value-ecmascript@1.1.0
├─ unicode-property-aliases-ecmascript@1.0.5
├─ union-value@1.0.1
├─ universalify@0.1.2
├─ unpipe@1.0.0
├─ unset-value@1.0.0
├─ urix@0.1.0
├─ use@3.1.1
├─ util-deprecate@1.0.2
├─ utils-merge@1.0.1
├─ uuid@3.3.3
├─ validate-npm-package-license@3.0.4
├─ vary@1.1.2
├─ walker@1.0.7
├─ whatwg-fetch@3.0.0
├─ which@1.3.1
├─ write-file-atomic@1.3.4
├─ xcode@2.0.0
├─ xmlbuilder@9.0.7
├─ xmldoc@1.1.2
├─ xmldom@0.1.27
├─ xpipe@1.0.5
├─ xtend@4.0.2
├─ y18n@3.2.1
└─ yargs-parser@7.0.0
Done in 118.90s.
info Setting up new React Native app in C:\test\test1
info Adding required dependencies
yarn add v1.19.1
[1/4] Resolving packages...
warning jest > jest-cli > jest-config > jest-environment-jsdom > jsdom > left-pad@1.3.0: use String.prototype.padStart()
[2/4] Fetching packages...
info fsevents@1.2.9: The platform "win32" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@1.2.9" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
warning "@react-native-community/eslint-config > eslint-plugin-react@7.12.4" has incorrect peer dependency "eslint@^3.0.0 || ^4.0.0 || ^5.0.0".
warning "@react-native-community/eslint-config > eslint-plugin-react-native@3.6.0" has incorrect peer dependency "eslint@^3.17.0 || ^4 || ^5".
warning "@react-native-community/eslint-config > @typescript-eslint/parser@1.13.0" has incorrect peer dependency "eslint@^5.0.0".
warning "@react-native-community/eslint-config > @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@1.13.0" has incorrect peer dependency "eslint@^5.0.0".
warning "@react-native-community/eslint-config > @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin > tsutils@3.17.1" has unmet peer dependency "typescript@>=2.8.0 || >= 3.2.0-dev || >= 3.3.0-dev || >= 3.4.0-dev || >= 3.5.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-beta || >= 3.7.0-dev || >= 3.7.0-beta".
[4/4] Building fresh packages...
success Saved lockfile.
success Saved 179 new dependencies.
info Direct dependencies
├─ @react-native-community/eslint-config@0.0.5
├─ eslint@6.6.0
├─ jest@24.9.0
├─ react-test-renderer@16.9.0
└─ react@16.9.0
info All dependencies
├─ @jest/core@24.9.0
├─ @jest/reporters@24.9.0
├─ @jest/test-sequencer@24.9.0
├─ @react-native-community/eslint-config@0.0.5
├─ @types/babel__core@7.1.3
├─ @types/babel__generator@7.6.0
├─ @types/babel__template@7.0.2
├─ @types/babel__traverse@7.0.7
├─ @types/eslint-visitor-keys@1.0.0
├─ @types/json-schema@7.0.3
├─ @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@1.13.0
├─ @typescript-eslint/parser@1.13.0
├─ acorn-globals@4.3.4
├─ acorn-jsx@5.1.0
├─ acorn-walk@6.2.0
├─ acorn@7.1.0
├─ ajv@6.10.2
├─ array-equal@1.0.0
├─ asn1@0.2.4
├─ asynckit@0.4.0
├─ aws-sign2@0.7.0
├─ aws4@1.8.0
├─ babel-eslint@10.0.1
├─ babel-plugin-jest-hoist@24.9.0
├─ babel-preset-jest@24.9.0
├─ bcrypt-pbkdf@1.0.2
├─ browser-process-hrtime@0.1.3
├─ browser-resolve@1.11.3
├─ caseless@0.12.0
├─ chardet@0.7.0
├─ cliui@5.0.0
├─ co@4.6.0
├─ combined-stream@1.0.8
├─ cssom@0.3.8
├─ cssstyle@1.4.0
├─ dashdash@1.14.1
├─ data-urls@1.1.0
├─ deep-is@0.1.3
├─ delayed-stream@1.0.0
├─ detect-newline@2.1.0
├─ diff-sequences@24.9.0
├─ doctrine@3.0.0
├─ domexception@1.0.1
├─ ecc-jsbn@0.1.2
├─ emoji-regex@7.0.3
├─ es-abstract@1.16.0
├─ es-to-primitive@1.2.1
├─ escodegen@1.12.0
├─ eslint-plugin-eslint-comments@3.1.2
├─ eslint-plugin-flowtype@2.50.3
├─ eslint-plugin-jest@22.4.1
├─ eslint-plugin-prettier@2.6.2
├─ eslint-plugin-react-hooks@1.7.0
├─ eslint-plugin-react-native-globals@0.1.2
├─ eslint-plugin-react-native@3.6.0
├─ eslint-plugin-react@7.12.4
├─ eslint-scope@5.0.0
├─ eslint-utils@1.4.3
├─ eslint@6.6.0
├─ espree@6.1.2
├─ esquery@1.0.1
├─ estraverse@4.3.0
├─ extend@3.0.2
├─ external-editor@3.1.0
├─ extsprintf@1.3.0
├─ fast-deep-equal@2.0.1
├─ fast-diff@1.2.0
├─ fast-levenshtein@2.0.6
├─ figures@3.1.0
├─ file-entry-cache@5.0.1
├─ flat-cache@2.0.1
├─ flatted@2.0.1
├─ forever-agent@0.6.1
├─ form-data@2.3.3
├─ getpass@0.1.7
├─ glob-parent@5.1.0
├─ handlebars@4.5.1
├─ har-schema@2.0.0
├─ har-validator@5.1.3
├─ has@1.0.3
├─ html-encoding-sniffer@1.0.2
├─ http-signature@1.2.0
├─ ignore@4.0.6
├─ import-fresh@3.1.0
├─ inquirer@7.0.0
├─ is-date-object@1.0.1
├─ is-extglob@2.1.1
├─ is-generator-fn@2.1.0
├─ is-glob@4.0.1
├─ is-regex@1.0.4
├─ is-symbol@1.0.2
├─ is-typedarray@1.0.0
├─ isstream@0.1.2
├─ istanbul-lib-instrument@3.3.0
├─ istanbul-lib-report@2.0.8
├─ istanbul-lib-source-maps@3.0.6
├─ istanbul-reports@2.2.6
├─ jest-changed-files@24.9.0
├─ jest-cli@24.9.0
├─ jest-docblock@21.2.0
├─ jest-each@24.9.0
├─ jest-environment-jsdom@24.9.0
├─ jest-environment-node@24.9.0
├─ jest-leak-detector@24.9.0
├─ jest-pnp-resolver@1.2.1
├─ jest-resolve-dependencies@24.9.0
├─ jest-watcher@24.9.0
├─ jest@24.9.0
├─ jsdom@11.12.0
├─ json-schema-traverse@0.4.1
├─ json-schema@0.2.3
├─ json-stable-stringify-without-jsonify@1.0.1
├─ json-stringify-safe@5.0.1
├─ jsprim@1.4.1
├─ jsx-ast-utils@2.2.3
├─ kleur@3.0.3
├─ left-pad@1.3.0
├─ levn@0.3.0
├─ load-json-file@4.0.0
├─ lodash.unescape@4.0.1
├─ mute-stream@0.0.8
├─ neo-async@2.6.1
├─ nwsapi@2.2.0
├─ oauth-sign@0.9.0
├─ object-inspect@1.6.0
├─ object.fromentries@2.0.1
├─ object.getownpropertydescriptors@2.0.3
├─ optimist@0.6.1
├─ optionator@0.8.3
├─ p-each-series@1.0.0
├─ p-reduce@1.0.0
├─ parent-module@1.0.1
├─ parse5@4.0.0
├─ path-type@3.0.0
├─ performance-now@2.1.0
├─ pn@1.1.0
├─ prettier@1.16.4
├─ progress@2.0.3
├─ prompts@2.2.1
├─ psl@1.4.0
├─ qs@6.5.2
├─ react-test-renderer@16.9.0
├─ react@16.9.0
├─ read-pkg-up@4.0.0
├─ read-pkg@3.0.0
├─ request-promise-core@1.1.3
├─ request-promise-native@1.0.8
├─ request@2.88.0
├─ resolve-cwd@2.0.0
├─ rxjs@6.5.3
├─ sisteransi@1.0.3
├─ sshpk@1.16.1
├─ stealthy-require@1.1.1
├─ string.prototype.trimleft@2.1.0
├─ string.prototype.trimright@2.1.0
├─ strip-json-comments@3.0.1
├─ symbol-tree@3.2.4
├─ table@5.4.6
├─ test-exclude@5.2.3
├─ text-table@0.2.0
├─ tough-cookie@2.5.0
├─ tslib@1.10.0
├─ tsutils@3.17.1
├─ tunnel-agent@0.6.0
├─ tweetnacl@0.14.5
├─ uglify-js@3.6.8
├─ uri-js@4.2.2
├─ util.promisify@1.0.0
├─ v8-compile-cache@2.1.0
├─ verror@1.10.0
├─ w3c-hr-time@1.0.1
├─ whatwg-encoding@1.0.5
├─ whatwg-mimetype@2.3.0
├─ whatwg-url@6.5.0
├─ word-wrap@1.2.3
├─ write-file-atomic@2.4.1
├─ write@1.0.3
├─ xml-name-validator@3.0.0
└─ yargs-parser@13.1.1
Done in 69.62s.
info Adding required dev dependencies
yarn add v1.19.1
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
warning Pattern ["@babel/core@^7.7.2"] is trying to unpack in the same destination "C:\\Users\\admin\\AppData\\Local\\Yarn\\Cache\\v6\\npm-@babel-core-7.7.2-ea5b99693bcfc058116f42fa1dd54da412b29d91-integrity\\node_modules\\@babel\\core" as pattern ["@babel/core@^7.0.0","@babel/core@^7.0.0","@babel/core@^7.0.0","@babel/core@^7.0.0","@babel/core@^7.0.0","@babel/core@^7.1.0","@babel/core@^7.1.0"]. This could result in non-deterministic behavior, skipping.
warning Pattern ["@babel/runtime@^7.7.2"] is trying to unpack in the same destination "C:\\Users\\admin\\AppData\\Local\\Yarn\\Cache\\v6\\npm-@babel-runtime-7.7.2-111a78002a5c25fc8e3361bedc9529c696b85a6a-integrity\\node_modules\\@babel\\runtime" as pattern ["@babel/runtime@^7.0.0"]. This could result in non-deterministic behavior, skipping.
info fsevents@1.2.9: The platform "win32" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@1.2.9" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
warning "@react-native-community/eslint-config > @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@1.13.0" has incorrect peer dependency "eslint@^5.0.0".
warning "@react-native-community/eslint-config > @typescript-eslint/parser@1.13.0" has incorrect peer dependency "eslint@^5.0.0".
warning "@react-native-community/eslint-config > eslint-plugin-react@7.12.4" has incorrect peer dependency "eslint@^3.0.0 || ^4.0.0 || ^5.0.0".
warning "@react-native-community/eslint-config > eslint-plugin-react-native@3.6.0" has incorrect peer dependency "eslint@^3.17.0 || ^4 || ^5".
warning "@react-native-community/eslint-config > @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin > tsutils@3.17.1" has unmet peer dependency "typescript@>=2.8.0 || >= 3.2.0-dev || >= 3.3.0-dev || >= 3.4.0-dev || >= 3.5.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-beta || >= 3.7.0-dev || >= 3.7.0-beta".
[4/4] Building fresh packages...
success Saved lockfile.
success Saved 7 new dependencies.
info Direct dependencies
├─ @babel/core@7.7.2
├─ @babel/runtime@7.7.2
├─ @react-native-community/eslint-config@0.0.5
├─ babel-jest@24.9.0
├─ eslint@6.6.0
├─ jest@24.9.0
└─ metro-react-native-babel-preset@0.57.0
info All dependencies
├─ @babel/core@7.7.2
├─ @babel/runtime@7.7.2
├─ @react-native-community/eslint-config@0.0.5
├─ babel-jest@24.9.0
├─ eslint@6.6.0
├─ jest@24.9.0
└─ metro-react-native-babel-preset@0.57.0
Done in 7.69s.

  Run instructions for iOS:
    • cd C:\test\test1 && react-native run-ios
    - or -
    • Open test1\ios\test1.xcodeproj in Xcode or run "xed -b ios"
    • Hit the Run button

  Run instructions for Android:
    • Have an Android emulator running (quickest way to get started), or a device connected.
    • cd C:\test\test1 && react-native run-android


C:\test>111
```

> Package.jason

```
{
  "name": "test2",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "16.9.0",
    "react-native": "0.61.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.7.2",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.7.2",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^0.0.5",
    "babel-jest": "^24.9.0",
    "eslint": "^6.6.0",
    "jest": "^24.9.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.57.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.9.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

Please! Help me with this

Comment: Which RN version you used?

Comment: @OliverD react-native-cli: 2.0.1 || I tried to install the built apk on my phone it doesn't install so the problem has to be the app itself

Comment: react-native-cli: 2.0.1 ||

Comment: Can you share your package.json here?

Comment: @OliverD  {
  "name": "test2",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "16.9.0",
    "react-native": "0.61.4"
  },

Comment: @OliverD part 2  ||    "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.7.2",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.7.2",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^0.0.5",
    "babel-jest": "^24.9.0",
    "eslint": "^6.6.0",
    "jest": "^24.9.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.57.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.9.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}

Comment: Are you follow this guide when you create a new project?https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started

Comment: I think so try to create your app with ```npx react-native init AwesomeProject```

Comment: @OliverD it finally worked OliverD thank you so much, you put it as the answer i'll confirm it once again thank you so much  : )